# VNC Client on Raspberry PI Zero

Tags: networking, usb, vnc

I need to use VNC Client on Raspberry PI Zero. It doesn't have network interfaces, so I probably need to connect Raspberry via mini-usb to my Android phone. How to configure such network (via USB)? Which VNC client USE? Is there KMS VNC client?

Comment: Does one of the answers help you? If so, please accept one. Only this will finish your question and it will not pop up again months for months.

Answer (score 0):

With the Raspberry Pi Zero (W) you can use OTG gadget mode. In this mode you are able to emulate a mini USB connection as ethernet interface so you can use it as regular network connection that also is usable by VNC. How to setup gadget mode look at [Raspberry Pi Zero OTG Mode](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41).